# How to add Trailing Slash at the end of directory ONLY

Tags: trailing-slash

How to add Trailing Slash at the end of directory only, not file?
example: with Trailing Slash:
`https://www.mywebsite.com/directory/`

example: without Trailing Slash:
`https://www.mywebsite.com/file.php`

Comment: Your question is not clear can you please elaborate so that everyone can understand.

Comment: There are two types of directions on a web: directory (such as https://www.mywebsite.com/) and file (such as https://www.mywebsite.com/file.php). I want to add Trailing Slash only at the directory not file